# ColdFusion debugging problem in Eclipse (Break points not hit)

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, eclipse-plugin, coldfusion-8

I am trying to get the debugger (CF extension for Eclipse) working for last few hours. And struck in strange situation.

My settings are listed below

- ColdFusion 8
- Eclipse 3.4

I set up the RDS & modified the JVM.config settings and verified the connection & debugger, both returns successful in test run. But When i attach a debugger to the site, breakpoints are not hit.

My Eclipse workbench & site virtual directory pointing to the same path. It is in a remote server.

I left Eclipse-CF mapping blank since both pointing the same remote path.

And i am using WYSE thin client emulator.. does it anything to do with this..?

Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If your eclipse configuration is ok, could be that something is not confgured right on server side. Check if Line Debugger Settings > Allow Line Debugging feature is enabled and that Debugger Port (5005) is opened and accessible form client machine.

Articles that should walk you through proper setup:

http://eclipse.sys-con.com/node/382427

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/debugger.html

Also you could try using CF Builder and/or FusionDebug http://www.fusion-debug.com/fd/ .

Comment: Hi Zarko, i have verified everything... all settings are perfect in server side too.... Debugger was just fine. when i attach a debugger it loaded everything... only problem is breakpoints are not hit... i assume there should be a problem in CF-eclipse mapping.. any ideas??

Comment: You need to put local path for example if you have mapped drive z:\yourappname, remote path would be for example C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourappname and URL prefix would be yourappname .

Answer (score 3):

You do need to specify at least one mapping. Eclipse needs to know what folder in your project maps to the http root. Even if the mapping is / -> /, you need to specify that. The only time you can leave mapping blank is when the CF server is on the same machine as Eclipse.

Comment: can you pls give the sample of mapping? for example, my site is in remote machine named "devpc" and i opened the code from the same path in eclipse local machine... how can i map that now?

Comment: For example, say your Eclipse project points to \\devpc\www. The ColdFusion server recognizes as D:\www. The mapping in Eclipse specifies that the Eclipse directory is \\devpc\www and the server is D:\www. Eclipse translates the file path (\\devpc\www) to a path that the ColdFusion server recognizes (D:\www).

See also: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/Using/WS0ef8c004658c1089-31c11ef1121cdfd6aa0-7fef.html